# Process builder not working properly

Tags: process-builder, approval-process

i have a requirement like Create Object B, when a object A's `Approval_Status__c==Approved`. I am using

- approval process for submitting the record for approval
- Process builder for automatically submitting the record for approval
- Process builder for creating object B when object A record field
  value==approved.

upto second step it is working as expected, but Object B is not creating. If i update the `Approval_Status__c==Approved` manually on object A then only process builder firing and creating object B. Why it is happening. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Approval process field update action we have one checkbox "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change". Make sure you need this checkbox is checked.

If you don't check this checkbox then Salesforce didn't run WF,Process builder again.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Tushar Sharma...its working fine...I need one more help in email template i am using {!Owner.Manager} but it is returning null... But i need to include record owner.manager.firstname please help me

Comment: @ApexCode Do not add follow up question in comments. Add a new question with complete details. You can accept the answer and close the question if it works for you.